# Is using realm to persist data between screens a good idea?

Tags: react-native, realm

I am a bit confused as to how realm can actually be incorporated. After reading about it my idea is to store data in a DB and then pull from the DB on load and save as a realm object. This object is then used to persist data between screens in my react native app and then saved to the DB when it is changed. It would then be deleted on app close from the realm DB and just kept on the server DB. So my main reason for using realm is to manipulate and use my data in the app and persist that data between the various screens. Is this a viable application for realm or would it be better to store in the DB and then pass the data directly between the screens on navigation?

```
function loginUser(){
    //fetch user from cloud DB
    //save user to realm object and store on phone
    return User
}

screen1(
    button(onPress => loginUser)
    if(User != null){
        navigate.navigation(screen2)
    }
)

screen2(
    User = //fetch user from realm object
    display(User)
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's important to make questions clear so we can attempt to answer. For example "pull data from DB".... Realm is a database so do you mean pull data from Realm or some other database? If another, what's the use case? Why *not* use Realm to store your data? What does "persist data... between screens" mean? Actually what do you mean by a "screen"? A window? A view? Something else? Keep in mind SO is a site to assist with existing code so most questions include some code so we understand what's being asked. Clarify what you're asking and we'll take a look!

Comment: Hi Jay, So I essentially want to fetch all the data from a cloud DB needed for a user when they log in and store it locally on the phone using realm. The reason I am thinking of doing is like this is because when a user is on the home page I would need some of the data from the user profile but when they navigate to another page (or screen) I would then need to use different data from the same profile. I will try make a high level mock up as I dont have the code for this example since its more of a question surrounding whether its a viable application of Realm.

Comment: *all the data from a cloud DB* - Realm is a local first, cloud DB so why not just use Realm? Moving around within an app often times requires passing data from one UI element to another. In iOS, they are called 'views' and you can pass data in a number of ways from one view to another (segues are popular) but that's unrelated to your database and more related to your apps model (MVC is also popular in macOs/iOS). The question is still pretty vague and needs clarity since what you're asking about is very common in programming. What specific issue is challenging you?